# Apache Alias with Laravel Issue

Tags: laravel, apache

I have API say xyz.com/api which is Live, working correctly, which is developed in Yii framework,I want to move this from Yii  to laravel.

So I am not touching the existing API, Whaever new task is coming want to move to laravel.

I am facing problem is setuping the laravel application.

My folder yii folder root is /var/yii  and laravel root folder is /var/laravel/public

My Yii URL is xyz.com/api and laravel url is xyz.com/newapi

I want all the request of xyz.com should reach to yii folder only xyz.com/newapi should reach to laravel folder.

I tried following to apache config

```
Alias /newapi /var/laravel/public
<Directory "/var/laravel/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

My laravel version is 5.4
Apache version is 2.2
I tried the same configuration with Lumen 5.2, it's working but for laravel it's not working.

If i tried xyz.com/newapi/newapi/login then it is working
but xyz.com/newapi/login is not working

My laravel routes looks something like this

`Route::post('newapi/login', 'LoginController@login');`

Answer (score 0):

Which route file are you using? If you're using the api.php route file, check if your api is running on xyz.com/newapi/api

You can remove the api prefix from RouteServiceProvider.php to remove the second api from the url.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood the original post. You need to remove 'newapi' from your laravel routes.